# Android Studio complaining Gradle version is too low

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android Studio is complaining that Gradle version is too low

```
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 7.0.
```

But when I check my Gradle version in Project Structure **it's clearly v7.2**

[image]

- I have checked for Android Studio updates and there are none.
- I have invalidated caches and restarted
- I have rebooted system and started Android Studio

> So why is Android Studio complaining and how do I remedy

Android Studio details

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.images.show.chessboard=true
```

In Project explorer in the .gradle folder there are multiple version folders.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle application file?

Answer (score 0):

You should try File ->Invalidate caches / Restart.

Two files change when gradle version is changed

1. build.gradle
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
2. gradle-wrapper.properties
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip

You can check these two files whether they are changed according to new version

Comment: Still get Gradle version exception

Comment: No gradle-wrapper.properties file in project and  build.gradle dependency `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`